# Replacing Python list comprehension with pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

It happens quite a lot that I want to create a list of function values, say, [f(0), f(2),... f(100)], and then plot the result. My go-to solution has been something like

```
x = list(range(101))
y = [f(n) for n in x]
plt.plot(x,y)
```

However, I am using pandas for most other stuff, and I was wondering if there is a neater way to do the same thing with pandas? It is possible to do something like

```
x = pd.Series(range(101))
y = x.apply(f)
y.plot()
```

but I feel awkward defining x like this. Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: What's awkward about this? What is it that you are trying to avoid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dont do this ... instead convert f to accept a pandas series

```
def f(x):
    return numpy.sin(x) + 3

x = pd.Series(range(101))
y = f(x)
```

series.apply is largely just a convenience function, it likely will not provide any speedup

if you just want range... just use `numpy.arange` it should perform as well as or better than a series at the next step

```
x = np.arange(101)
y = f(x)
```

and if you dont care about x later you can just pass arange directly

```
y = f(np.arange(101))
plt.plot(y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: or without pandas `y=list(map(f, x))`

Comment: @ansev the OP already has a perfectly good approach for doing this without pandas... The whole point of the question is to use pandas